# Reading XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have the following xml

```
<Objects>
    <Object>
        <ViewAngle>90</ViewAngle>
        <ViewMode>ThirdPerson</ViewMode>
        <Top>50</Top>
        <Left>100</Left>
    </Object>
</Objects>
```

I have the following code to read this xml

```
           XmlDataDocument doc = new XmlDataDocument();
           doc.Load(xmlPath);
           XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
           XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/Objects/Object");
           foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
           {
                if (node.InnerXml.Contains("View"))
                {
                  string viewType=node["View"].InnerText;
                  //..... other stuffs
                }
                if (node.InnerXml.Contains("ViewAngle"))
                {
                  string viewAngle=node["ViewAngle"].InnerText;
                  //..... other stuffs
                }
                if (node.InnerXml.Contains("ViewMode"))
                {
                  string viewMode=node["ViewMode"].InnerText;
                  //..... other stuffs
                }
           }
```

Above code is working fine if my xml contains one more tag i.e. `<View>3dView</View>`. But if it does not contains the View tag, then it produces error.

The `InnerXml.Contains()` is a simple string method that checks for the sub-string is present in the string or not.

In my case the `Contains("View")` returns true as *View* is present in *ViewAngle* and in *ViewMode* that is why it is going inside the if block of **View** but when it tries to read the `node["View"]`, it produces error as **View** node is not exists in the xml.

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the fact that XML is structured data, not string. This is *completely* the wrong approach:

```
if (node.InnerXml.Contains("View")) {
  // ...
}
```

You want this:

```
XmlNode child = node.SelectSingleNode("./View");
if (child != null) {
  // now do something with 'child' ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this loop instead:

```
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes) {
            foreach (XmlNode prop in node.ChildNodes) {
                if (prop.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element)
                    continue;

                switch (prop.Name) {
                    case "View":
                        string viewType = prop.InnerText;
                        // ...
                        break;

                    case "ViewAngle":
                        string viewAngle = prop.InnerText;
                        // ...
                        break;

                    case "ViewMode":
                        string viewMode = prop.InnerText;
                        // ...
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the *View* element is not present, it cannot be found. You can use the GetElementsByTagName("View") method instead. This will return null if the *view* element is not there.

Answer (score 0):

You can make some modifications in this function and use it acordingly

```
 XDocument xDoc=XDocument.Load(@"C:\File.xml");            
Process(xDoc.Root);


public static void Process(XElement element)
        {
            if (element.HasElements)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("<" + element.Name.LocalName + ">");
                foreach (XElement child in element.Elements())
                {
                    Process(child);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("<" + element.Name.LocalName + ">");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("<" + element.Name.LocalName);
                if(element.HasAttributes)
                {
                    foreach (XAttribute attr in element.Attributes())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(attr.Name +"="+attr.Value);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(">" + element.Value + "</" + element.Name.LocalName + ">");  
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if trageting 3.5 or above u can use linq

```
XDocument XDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\UrXMLFile.xml");


var q = from b in xml.Descendants("product")
        select new
        {
            View      = (string)b.Element("View") ?? "3dView",
            ViewAngle = (double?)b.Element("ViewAngle") ?? 90.0,                    
            ViewMode  = (string)b.Element("ViewMode") ?? ThirdPerson,
            Top       = (double?)b.Element("Top") ?? 0.0,
            Left      = (double?)b.Element("Left") ?? 0.0
        };
```

So if View is not found it have a default value always. Also u can create ur class object in select new. Note: I have not compiled it.